# Confusion about a Measure Theory problem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to solve the following problem (1.76)

[image]

This problem is taken from Junghenn's Principles of Analysis book.

According to the mentioned book, we have the following.

If $\mu^*$ is an outer measure in $[0,1]$, then $\mathcal{M}(\mu^*)$ denote the set of all $\mu^*$-measurable sets.

Recall that $E\subseteq [0,1]$ is a $\mu^*$-measurable set if for all $C\subseteq [0,1]$ we have $\mu^*(C)=\mu^* (C \cap E)+ \mu^* (C \cap E^c).$

In the other hand, the function $\lambda$ just assigns the lenght to a left-open interval $(a,b];$ that is, $\lambda ((a,b])=b-a.$ Note that $\lambda$ is *not* an outer measure since it is not defined in all $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}).$

So my first confusion is here: The set $\mathcal{M}(\mu^*)$ is defined if $\mu^*$ is an outer measure, right? But the problem states that $B\in \mathcal{M}(\lambda),$ but again, $\lambda$ is not an outer measure. So, what does it means $\mathcal{M}(\lambda)?$ Is this a possible errata?

My second confusion is here: Since $\lambda (B)=1,$ and $B\subseteq [0,1]$, then does it follows that $B=[0,1)?$ I conclude that since first of all, $\lambda$ is defined for the left open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ according to the book mentioned. So $B$ must be a left open interval of lenght $1$ that is contained in $[0,1]$, so $B$ must be $(0,1]$, isn't it?

If you have the chance, it would be helpful to check the chapter 1 of the Junghenn's book Principles of Analysis to get a better backround about what am I talking about.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The definition of $\lambda$ is the last line of text prior to the Exercises containing the quoted exercise.  $\lambda$ is there defined to be an outer measure (restricted to its measurable sets).

Comment: @EricTowers You're right! For some reason I didn't see that definition; Thank you so much; Now all has sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your second question, No.  $B$ can be $[0,1]$ minus any measure zero set.  For instance, $[0,1/2) \cup (1/2,1]$.  In fact, $B$ can be any (up to countable) union of intervals whose sum of lengths is $1$.

Think carefully about what exercise 1.71 is telling you: that you do not care whether the endpoints are included in any of these intervals.

Comment: Thanks! Now all is clear for me